# File permission vs directory permission

Tags: linux, filesystems

In Linux, if I have a file that is writable (chmod 771) inside a directory that is not writable (chmod 551), will the file be writable if I access it through that directory?

I have tested it and writing is possible, but my guts tell me that it shouldn't be possible.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Permissions are not recursive.

Comment: A directory is basically just a special file that maps names to files, and the write permissions just affect whether you can make changes to those mappings.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might correct me if I'm wrong, but Linux folders can be considered as "files" in this case. I mean, the content of a folder are the files and sub-folders it contains - if you remove the write permission, you are forbidding people from adding/removing files basically (and changing folder properties).

The files inside that folder doesn't inherit the folder's properties. Since the list of files remains the same (which is actually the content of that "file"), you can change the content of each file (as long as you have permission to edit that file).

Comment: Write permissions have nothing to do with changing directory properties.

Comment: So, you are saying if the directory is not writable, we can still write to files that already exist, but we cannot create new files?

Comment: you may make a dummy test for that - create a folder and a file inside it, and play with the permissions...